# How to reduce cpu usage while get frames

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a project where I need to use 20 cameras to perform operations. My problem is that when I take more than 4 cameras using opencv, cpu usage reaches over 90%.
How do I increase the number of cameras so that my cpu usage to be lower?
For example I am thinking about using vlc to read frames but have no idea how to implement them.
My system info is:cpu 9700k core i7,gpu nvidia 1080 ti,32gb ram.

```
     import cv2
     Cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp example...")
     while True:
              ret,frame=cap.read()
              cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
```

This is example for capture one camera.and im using another instances for other cameras.
In fact, I'm working on a face recognition system that uses the ip cameras to retrieve rtsp streams (opencv library) and apply my deep learning algorithms on these frames. The server system I listed above can only have 4 cameras and no more than the cpu usage allows for adding cameras.
My first question is how to effectively increase the number of cameras with reasonable fps
And the second question is how to choose the right hardware for these types of projects?

Comment: How are you reading in your frames at the moment? (Aka. can you add a code sample). And do the streams need to communicate?

Answer (score 0):

I made it faster by reading the frames in using FFmpeg directly. There might be better ways to do this but its an approvement. I assume you already start the videocaptures in different processes, is that correct? Otherwise, this would be a wise step too.

```
import numpy
from multiprocessing import Process
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import cv2

class ffmpeg_videocapture:
    def __init__(self, stream, width=640, height=360, scale=1, fps=15):
        self.command = 'ffmpeg -rtsp_transport udp -i {i} -pix_fmt bgr24 -s {w}x{h} -vcodec rawvideo ' \
                       '-an -sn -r {fps} -f image2pipe pipe:1'

        self.stream = stream
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.scale = scale
        self.fps = fps

        self.errors = []
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        width = int(self.width * self.scale)
        height = int(self.height * self.scale)
        command = self.command.format(i=self.stream, w=width, h=height, fps=self.fps)
        self.capture = Popen(command.split(' '), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, bufsize=10 ** 8)

    def read(self):
        width = int(self.width * self.scale)
        height = int(self.height * self.scale)
        raw_image = self.capture.stdout.read(width * height * 3)

        frame = numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
        frame = frame.reshape((height, width, 3))

        self.capture.stdout.flush()

        return frame is not None, frame

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.capture.terminate()


def single_camera(rtsp_stream):
    cap = ffmpeg_videocapture(rtsp_stream)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rtsp_stream_list = [
        "rtsp_stream_1",
        "rtsp_stream_2",
        "etc...",
    ]

    for rtsp_stream in rtsp_stream_list:
        t = Process(target=single_camera, args=(rtsp_stream,))
        t.start()
```

Comment: Does it work with rtsp as well?
How to include rtsp stream in this code?
Is it possible to add 20 cameras for processing using this method and hardware available?

Comment: Window not showing.i faced with empty window and after seconds force quit.

Comment: Error is:cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (360,480,3)

Comment: Ok thank you so much,i used this code and i successfully showing frame,is it possible for add 20 cameras in processing?how i use this code for multiple cameras?

Comment: I edited my answer, did not test It like this but it should work.

Comment: But after a few seconds the frames freeze

Comment: Is your rtsp stream udp or tcp?

Comment: That is ip camera

Comment: You might want leave the '-rtsp_transport udp' out

Comment: @JopKnoppers I've tried using the solution you wrote above and it tells me "Process" is not defined. Do I need an additional import for this?

Comment: Yes 'from multiprocessing import Process' will have to be added. Thank you for notifying me. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @JopKnoppers Thanks for the quick reply. I've included the import and that works fine. I have included my stream names in the stream list array and tried to run. I get the error `Type Error: single_camera() takes 1 positional argument but 39 were given`. Any idea why?

Comment: @CalMac should be fixed now, i was not able to test though

Comment: @JopKnoppers That worked. Is this solution only for local files? I put in an address to a rtsp stream and I got a file not found error.

Comment: @CalMac this should work for rtsp stream, that is what I'm using it for. If it doesn't work for you can you give me some more information about your issue?

Comment: @JopKnoppers Running through it with the debugger it seems to stop and give an error after `self.capture = Popen(command.split(' '), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, bufsize=10 ** 8)`. The error is just `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.